# What's the Perforce workflow equivalent to this Git workflow? Shelves?

Tags: git, perforce

I have done a fairly large refactor, built a binary and submitted to QA for testing. I'd like to start working on a new feature while waiting for QA to come back, with the assumption that I might have to go back and change some things based on QA results.

In Git I would do my refactoring on a branch `bigRefactor`, make a build based on that, submit to QA, then branch `postBigRefactorNewFeature` from `bigRefactor` and continue working. When QA comes back with required changes, I would switch back to `bigRefactor`, make the required changes, commit, then switch to `postBigRefactorNewFeature` and either `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick` to bring my changes from `bigRefactor` into `postBigRefactorNewFeature`.

In Perforce the best I can come up with is to shelve the files I've used for QA on changelist A with description 'big refactor' without reverting locally, move the local changes (now copied to the shelf) to a new changelist B with description 'post big refactor new feature', then continue working. When QA comes back I'll have to shelve what I'm working on in changelist B, revert, unshelve from changelist A, make the required changes, then somehow merge the files from the shelf in changelist B into the workspace.

As far as I can tell there's no way to merge a shelf into the current state of the workspace. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use shelves as miniature branches using the workflow you describe. Perforce takes case of the "somehow merge the files from the shelf" part.

You can merge changes from a shelf into the current state of the workspace, as long as you have a sufficiently recent server release (I believe this functionality was added in release 2011.1, though it might have been a bit later than that).

You can 'unshelve into open files'; when you unshelve a shelf which has edits to files that you currently have open, Perforce schedules a resolve between the shelved changes and your open files.

The overall process is very similar to other resolves, and is very straightforward to use.

Here's the release note for the new feature.

```
#299614 (Bug #38221, #39099) **
    Unshelving a file opened for edit over a file already opened
    for edit in the workspace is now allowed. A resolve record is
    created when unshelving, and the user must then run 'p4 resolve'
    to resolve the workspace files with the shelved files.
```

Other recent shelving features include the ability to unshelve through a branch spec, and the ability to directly submit a shelved change without unshelving it first. Shelves have evolved quite a bit in recent releases.

You might set up a small test server and experiment with this a bit so that you understand in more detail how it works, and ask more precise questions if the Perforce behavior is confusing.

That said, my own experience is that if your workflow is complicated enough, it becomes confusing to do the "use-shelves-as-mini-branches" approach, and so at some point it's OK to simply make branches. Perforce fully supports branches, of course, even though the precise mechanics are different than git.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Having used P4 for another few months, shelves don't really cut it. Unfortunately Perforce branches are severely lacking in some ways - eg there's no way to cherry-pick just a diff between two revisions on a branch, so if I fix a bug on a branch as part of a refactor, I can't bring *just* the bugfix back onto the main branch because Perforce wants to merge the entire file, not just the diff hunks that fix the bug.

Comment: I cherry-pick as you describe all the time. I simply do: p4 integrate //depot/branch/...@=NNN //depot/main/..., where NNN is the particular changelist I want to integrate. And there are many more examples: see 'p4 help revisions' for more details.

Comment: "There's no way to cherry pick just a diff between two revisions on a branch". This means, if I submit branch/file.cs#1, branch/file.cs#2, branch/file.cs#3, there is no way to bring *just* the diff between #2 and #3 over to main/file.cs, ignoring the diff between #1 and #2.

Comment: For me, 'p4 integrate branch/file.cs#3,#3 main/file.cs' does exactly the right thing. But maybe I'm still mis-understanding. Perhaps you just need to spell it out in more detail, or maybe set up a test server and play with it some more? The syntax of 'p4 integrate' is indeed fiendishly complicated, and it takes a while to learn how to use it. Have you tried using a visual client, like P4V?